# What particular concerns are there for a chaotic evil PC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment

The other day a person at school asked what I though of him playing as a chaotic evil character, I said I wasn’t sure. But as I think about it I become more and more confused. Why might it be a bad idea to let a PC play as a alignment of chaotic evil? Of course the general idea of a rpg is to work together, so would allowing him to do this clash with that concept?

Comment: What alignment are the other PC's playing? What is the goal/purpose of the campaign?

Comment: This question is extremely borderline with respect to our rules for what alignment questions are and are not on topic, but for now I’m falling in favor of leaving it. You may want to review [the discussion around those rules](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357/4563), though I doubt this question could be changed to fit those rules better. See also Q&As about [problems with Chaotic Neutral (closed)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/18937/4563) and [challenges when playing an Evil character (closed)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2478/4563).

Comment: Also related, [What is “My Guy Syndrome”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37103/4563), since some feel that My Guy Syndrome is either worse or more frequent with CE characters. (Personally, I think all alignments are equally-bad for this, since the real problem is players thinking they’re supposed to be playing their alignment rather than playing a character.)

Comment: I think we can manage a primer on how alignment clashes can be a difficult group dynamic without having to get into the off-topic issues of defining alignments. It’s a well-known enough problem, which we can explain to those who haven’t learned about it first-hand yet.

Comment: @Korvin We easily might. I don’t remember one off the top of my head, but that’s more a function of the site’s question set having expanded beyond my ready memory sometime in the last couple years.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have [a related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31818/22566), but there are more questions to look through.  Also related is [this question on alignments](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48521/22566).  This one [related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104937/22566) but again, no primer as you suggested ... maybe this is a golden opportunity.

Comment: More related answer [that touches on alignments differing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28802/22566).  [And this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107025/22566).  If none of these help, please clarify your question further.  What problem are you trying to solve?